# Redux props are being received in Redux DevTools but not in the React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am passing down a Redux prop to a component that is sourced from a fetch payload. The payload successfully changes state in my reducer and according to my Redux DevTools the component that I am trying to pass the state down to as a prop successfully receives the prop (an array of objects that is fetched in the action) yet when I console.log the prop or try to do anything with it it shows up as an empty array.

My index reducer:

```
export default combineReducers({
  cart: cartitemReducer,
  products: productReducer,
})
```

The fetch action:

```
export const fetchCart = () => dispatch => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/cartitems/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(cartjson =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_CART',
        payload: cartjson
    }))
}
```

The reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  userCart: [],
  cartItem: {}
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        userCart: action.payload
      };
```

mapping state to props:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  cart: state.cart.userCart
})
```

When I console.log(this.props.cart) it returns an empty array. Yet my DevTools correctly show the contents of the array under cart.userCart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on where you are `console.log()`-ing. If you run that in `componentDidMount()`, then you would just get an empty-array because `console.log()` runs before you complete the fetch-request and update your reducers. `componentDidMount()` will not trigger again.

However, your code looks to be set-up correctly. You should be able to print your results in `componentDidUpdate()`, which is triggered anytime you get updated props or state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(prevProps.cart.length !== this.props.cart.length){
    console.log(this.props.cart)
 }
}
```

Comment: You're exactly right and that's a big YIKES on my part. Was hammering away at this for the good part of an hour. Food deprivation is a killer.... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @deejay123 Lool. You're welcome! Gots to eat, food is fuel for the brain and happiness :).  If you have any other questions, let me know.